# How to find latitude and longitude from an address in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I m developing one application in which i m having the address of particular person, now i want to find the location of that person on google map. I want to save the latitude and longitude of that person when i m saving his details. How can i find the latitude and longitude from the address?

In address, i m saving his city, state , country, street, etc.

Thanks,
Saloni

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490622/get-latitude-and-longitude-based-on-location-name-google-maps-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you want to do is called **geocoding**, see the [page on Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

**Update:**

Probably you will need this function. It is able to iterate over an array and execute a callback after each geocoding return:

```
function locate(address, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(),
        latlong = [];

    geocoder.geocode({
        address: address[0]
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            latlong.push([results[0].geometry.location.Ma, results[0].geometry.location.Na]);
            address.shift();
            if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(latlong);

            if (address.length === 0) {
                return;
            } else {
                locate(address, callback);
            }
        }
    });
}


/*
 * Sample use
 */
locate(['1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA', '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA'], function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

**Don't forget to include Google Maps API JS file before your script.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Lapple, Can u tell me how can i use the code at selection of one dropdownlist?

Answer (score 0):

Use google Geocode API. Also following should help.

```
string url = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", address);
```

This would return you an xml with following inside  node

```
<location><lat>12.3456</lat><lng>98.7654</lng></location>
```

Answer (score 0):

I "third" the google geocoder..
here's an example in javascript:

```
//this is fired on the onChange of a dropdown or textbox
     function SetMap(textbox) {

        var postcode = textbox.value;
        if (postcode != '') {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': postcode }, GeoCodeResult);

        }

    }

    function GeoCodeResult(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var latlng = results[0].geometry.location.lat() + ', ' +                      results[0].geometry.location.lng();

//set hidden field to lat long
            document.getElementById('<%= hdnMapCoords.ClientID %>').value = latlng;


        }
    }
```

Comment: i want to do the same functionality as saloni wanted . But i want to do it in Asp.net with C# . how can i do it? can you help me ? thanks..

Comment: The above javascript is used with ASP.net and C#. If you are using googles API you have to use Javascript.